# C# export datatable to excel spreadsheet *object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, sql, excel, datatable

Hey folks I am trying to export a datatable to an excel spreadsheet (excel 15.0 library, excel 2013, VS 2013), and I am running into an issue. Right now I'm not worried so much about getting column headers and all that I'd just be happy with getting the data into the spreadsheet, my code is below and when I run it I keep getting

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

on the

```
workSheet.Cells[(i+2),(j+1)]
```

line of code.

```
public static void exportReport(System.Data.DataTable Results)
{
        try
        {
            string excelFilePath = @"C:\exceltest\exceltestsheet.xlsx"; 

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet workSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

            if (Results == null || Results.Columns.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("null or empty table");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < Results.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Results.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    workSheet.Cells[(i + 2), (j + 1)] = Results.Rows[i][j];
                }
            }

            if (excelFilePath != null && excelFilePath != "")
            {
                workSheet.SaveAs(excelFilePath);
                excelApp.Quit();
                Console.WriteLine("Excel File Saved!");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
}
```

Comment: Check if `workSheet` is null or not

Comment: Maybe change it to Worksheet.Cells[(i + 2), (j +1)].Value ??  But this is a VERY slow way to write to Excel, you might want to look at using OpenXML instead?  Even the ADO CopyFromRecordset method is much faster than writing a cell at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to create a new workbook before accessing the active sheet.  Try:

```
excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
```

BEFORE accessing the active worksheet.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my issue! I appreciate it. I've actually had this problem many times in the past and my work-around was always exporting to a text file and then just opening it/saving it as an .xlsx. But this will benefit me a ton. Thanks again!